# Xamarin.UWP RichTextBlock Hanging Indentation

Tags: xamarin, uwp, richtextblock

I used custom renderer to display a Label as RichTextBlock.  Using Paragraph, there is a TextIndentProperty to indent first line. However, I also need "Hanging Indentation" found in RichEditBox or SetIndent found in ITextParagraphFormat.

Is there a way to implemnent "Hanging Indentation" in RichTextBlock?

Comment: It is impossible that  implement  *Hanging Indentation* with `RichTextBlock`. As you can see [`Paragraph`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.paragraph) class only has [`TextIndent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.paragraph.textindent#Windows_UI_Xaml_Documents_Paragraph_TextIndent) property that used to set the indentation of the first line of text in a paragraph, it could not other line.

Comment: After plowing through the documentation, I guess it is impossible.  If I switch to RichEditBox (which support ITextDocument that supports Hanging Indentation), I cannot enter my Paragraph class.  Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this question.
Use left-padding to shift the entire paragraph in (say 10px)
Then, use text-indent with negative value to shift the first line of the paragraph out again (say -10px).
With this method, a hanging indentation can be achieved.